# Nodejs: Running process before another process is done

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, process, pipe

I've running this process in a node program

```
recorder = spawn("avconv", ["-y", "-r", "30", "-g", "300",
                "-f", "x11grab",
                "-s", "1024x768",
                "-i", process.env.DISPLAY,
                "-vcodec", "qtrle", "my_videos/the_video.mov"]);
```

This code uses the `avconv` program for record a video. The problem it's that after that the record video it's done i need running another process that use the output file for the first process

```
spawn("avconv", ["-y", 
            "-i","my_videos/the_video.mov",
            "-filter:v", "'setpts=5.0*PTS'",
            "my_videos/slowed_video.mov"]);
```

Is there anyway to create a pipe for the first process to the second process ?

Comment: Did you try spawnSync instead of spawn?

Comment: Its not possible because the first process records my testing suite, when the testing suite it's done, this process it's done and then i need run the second process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `spawn` API documentation.

**See:** https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess

You should be able to listen for the process `close` event using the `on` api.

Example:

```
var AVCONV_OK = 0; // assuming 0 indicates SUCCESS, which what most executable reports.

recorder = spawn("avconv", ["-y", "-r", "30", "-g", "300",
                "-f", "x11grab",
                "-s", "1024x768",
                "-i", process.env.DISPLAY,
                "-vcodec", "qtrle", "my_videos/the_video.mov"]);

recorder.on('close', (returnCode) => { 
    if (returnCode === AVCONV_OK) {
        // Spawn the 2nd process to do step 2.
    }
    else {
        console.log("oops recording failed.");
    }
});
```

**Note:** The code above is pure pseudo only, I can't test it as I don't use `avconv`.

Alternatively you can do like what other suggested on comment. Use `spawnSync` which returns you an object that contains parameters like `status` and `output` etc.

Either way is fine, the only benefit of doing async is that your nodeJS app can still work on other stuff while you wait for `avconv` to finish running.

For `spawnSync` see:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options